# How can i draw on image background in codenameone?

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to draw graphics(such as line, polygon and more) on a image in codenameone framework.

I write some codes like below, but i got error and it's not working.

How can i do such a thing anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

```
currentForm = new Form();
currentForm.setLayout(new LayeredLayout());
currentForm.applyRTL(true);
final Container mapContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.RIGHT));
currentForm.addComponent(mapContainer);
Image mapImg = res.getImage("t_map.png");
mapContainer.getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage(mapImg);
mapContainer.getUnselectedStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);

paints(mapImg.getGraphics());

public void paints(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(0xeecccc);
    g.fillRadialGradient(0xffffff, 0x334561, 0,0,90, 200);

    g.setColor(0xeecccc);
    g.fillRect(10, 10, 80, 130);

    g.setColor(0xcceecc);
    g.drawString("Write on Graphic",100, 150);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mutable image which isn't the default, a mutable image is created via `Image.createImage(int width,int height)` or `Image.createImage(int width,int height, int argbBackgroundColor)`.

Those images will allow `getGraphics()` to work properly and paint, you can then draw the image you got from the resources onto that mutable image.